# AWS Amplify AppSync GraphQL @Auth directive: How can I forbid to list of elements for public user

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, authorization, aws-amplify

I am creating an React App with Amplify backend. So far that is working great but I want to forbid that certain user can list some Elements. Let me give an example graphql definition:

```
type Customer @model 
@auth(rules: [
   {allow: public, , operations: [read,create,update]},
   {allow: groups, groups: ["admin","partner"] }])  
{
   id: ID!
   firstName: String
   lastName: String
   email: String
   phone: String
}
```

We have Customers that are not logged in so they are public. They know their id (because it is in the url after they created the Customer Entry) and they should be able to update, read and create their own user. Thats working good.
**Unfortunately they can also use the listCustomers query.** So they can see all the other entries. Can I forbid this in some way? As I understand the operation "read" means "get" and "list".

The same should be for cognito groups. "admin" should be able to do everything including "list" and "partner" should only be able to "get".

Does anyone has an idea? I have read the docs and googled it but seems like I do not find an answer.

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

To answer my question:

You can add { allow: public, queries: [get, list], mutations: [create,update]} for authorization rules. Unfortunately this is deprecated. I have no idea if there will be sth similar in the futur.

See: https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/graphql-transformer/auth/#definition

```
type Customer @model @auth(rules: [
    { allow: public, queries: [get], mutations: [create,update]},
    { allow: groups, groups: ["admin"] },
    { allow: groups, groups: ["partner"], queries: [get],  mutations: []}])  
{
id: ID!
firstName: String
lastName: String
email: String
phone: String
request: [Request] @connection(keyName: "byCustomer", fields: ["id"])
}
```